# how to use ng-switch-when for not empty json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch, angularjs-ng-switch

I an new in angularjs and I have json in my angularjs application, I want ng-switch to work when that json is not empty(it is an array). it's a large json and I'm talking about one part of it,is it possible with ng-switch? or I should set scope parameter in my controller? or some other ways that I do not know of

**JSON**

```
...,
"venues": [{"vid":"12",...},{"vid":"13",},{"vid":"14",..}],...
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-switch on="team.venues" >
    <ul ng-switch-when="venue is not empty">
        <li ng-repeat="venue in team.venues">
            {{venue.vid}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-s­wit­ch-­def­ault>no venue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can just use ng-if or ng-show why the switch, not clear from the question

Comment: @shaunhusain I'm new in angularjs, and you are right,I think ng-if is a better solution,thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use direct expression there like `ng-switch-when="team.venues.length > 0 && team.venues"`.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-switch on="team.venues">
     <ul ng-switch-when="team.venues.length > 0 && team.venues">
       <li ng-repeat="venue in team.venues">
          {{venue.vid}}
       </li>
     </ul>
     <p ng-s­wit­ch-­def­ault>no venue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if there is no `venues` property in `team` object then surely will be a error.

Comment: @K.Toress take a look at here.. http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4FqGD6p7a3AHkKjBkvM?p=preview it won't break..

Comment: :( say if there is no `vanue` property in `team` object, then `team.venues.length` this will surely get a error.

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi Happy Coding :p  :)

Answer (score 2):

yes use like this

```
<div ng-switch on="team.venues.length > 0" >
            <ul ng-switch-when="true">
                <li ng-repeat="venue in team.venues">
                 {{venue.vid}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p ng-s­wit­ch-­def­ault>no venue</p>
</div>
```

this will show the `<ul ng-switch-when="true">` when `team.venues.length > 0` is `true`.

this is what [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) says,

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
    <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
    <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
    <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

here is a official [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Hd8SB3pNjWIaSVA90UX?p=preview)

Comment: why not when its empty `team.venues.length` gets  the value `0`

Comment: thank you ;) it was usefull,but I think @PankajParkar answer was better. +1 for your answer